# The containing arrow function captures the global value of 'this'

Tags: node.js, typescript

this my code

```
import {EventEmitter} from 'events';
var emt = new EventEmitter();

emt.on('myEvent', () => {
    console.log('Arrow function: ')
    console.log(this)
});

emt.emit('myEvent');
```

in line `console.log(this)` I get Error.

> The containing arrow function captures the global value of 'this'.

What is the reason? How to fix it?

Comment: the answer is don't use an arrow function in this case. Also curious why you tagged this with typescript when there is no typescript in this code?

Comment: @DanStarns because this typescript throws an error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What is the reason?

Arrow functions, unlike regular function declarations, don't redefine `this`.  This is a huge convenience, usually.

In your case, `this` just means the global scope since there is no other context.  If your function was inside another closure, `this` would reference it instead of the global.

> How to fix it?

Did you mean to use `this` here?  If so, use `window` or whatever you actually wanted.

Comment: "Arrow functions, unlike regular function declarations, don't redefine this."  
Thank you for that, I was looking for this simple phrase.